# Business logic that needs to be reused, where should I placed it?

Tags: oop, model-view-controller, business-logic, separation-of-concerns

I have business logic like this that I need to reuse. My business logic is ordered like this:

```
User.Save();  
Payroll.Calculate();  
Mailer.Send();
```

Currently it's in my controller, but I want it to use in another controller. Where should I place that business logic and if there's design pattern what is it?

Sorry for noob question.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this business logic, it's more workflow coordination logic. Usually there is an extra application service layer where such logic lives. Controllers are then just calling on application services. Could you show your real code sample and the whole method, it would be useful if you want us to propose you reusable abstractions.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't post the real code. However, can you show me sample of application service layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Application Service for such logic as plalx suggests.
Good explanation of different options for designing application services you can find in the last chapter of the follwoing book:
[https://www.amazon.com/Implementing-Domain-Driven-Design-Vaughn-Vernon/dp/0321834577](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321834577)

I would suggest also to look at hexagonal architecture:
http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture

Answer (score 1):

It's not that simple question as can looks like at first time. I would tell that answer to question WHERE will depend on few factors:
1. Does this piece of business logic interacts with other Services?
2. Does this piece of business logic need to interact with repositories?
3. Does this peace of business logic affects more then one entity?
And more. Depends on the answers to that questions I would choose one:
Put business logic directly to Entity if it really describes what Entity should really do or move it to Domain Model Service. Sometimes I use more layers to keep everything Clear, independent and simple.

One of the key concepts of DDD is Ubiquitos language and you should write your domain model in the way it represents your ubiquitos language in code. So, first think about your domain model and then about patterns to use to achieve the result.

I would recommend you to check [Marco Pivetta's presentations](http://ocramius.github.io/talks/), he often shows some real good DDD examples.